# How to copy an entire sheets values as static into another sheet using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take a sheet like:
[image]
A3,B3,C3 are the sum of the 2 values above them.

Copy this entire sheet into another sheet with only static values ie the sum formulas are gone and 5,73,55 are just the values.

```
Public Sub CopyEntireSheetValues()
    Sheets("Static Data").Range("A1:M100").Value = Sheets("MAIN").Range("A1:M100").Value
End Sub
```

This works but ideally, i wouldn't define this range and copy all values from one sheet to another

Comment: `Sheets("Static Data").Range("A1:C100").Value = Sheets("MAIN").Range("A1:C100").Value`

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question since this does remove formulas but in the example the 20 and 55 aren't copied

Comment: The 20 and 55 aren't in your static sheet because they are outside the specified range of A1:C100.  If you want everything everywhere, just use .UsedRange

Comment: @tigeravatar sorry that was stupid, it works if i just use A1:M100 for example but the .UsedRange might be a better idea. Doing this ```Sheets("Static Data").UsedRange.Value = Sheets("MAIN").UsedRange.Value``` only copies the 20 over

Comment: @danielstafford thanks for accepting. Try to be a little more clear in your initial question. In this case the key condition you were missing was a dynamic range. Glad it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways. The exact method to do what you want is use the `pastespecial` method which would be as follows:

```
Public Sub CopyEntireSheetValues()

    Sheets("MAIN").Range("A1:C100").Copy
    Sheets("Static Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    
   
End Sub
```

The other is as explained in comment just setting values.

```
Sheets("Static Data").Range("A1:C100").Value = Sheets("MAIN").Range("A1:C100").Value
```

In general the setting values is probably the best. The only time I've used the `pasteValues` is sometimes dates don't quite behave the same when using the second method, but the end result should be the same.

You updated your question, but this could be dynamic (I didn't test).

```
Public Sub CopyEntireSheetValues()

    Sheets("MAIN").UsedRange.Copy
    Sheets("Static Data").Range(Sheets("MAIN").UsedRange.Address).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the setting values doesn't capture the 20 and 55 in the example, super confused as to why

Answer (score 2):

Here's commented code for how I'd accomplish this task via `.UsedRange`

```
Sub CopyEntireSheetValues()
    
    'Define and declare workbook and worksheet variables
    Dim wb As Workbook:     Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = wb.Worksheets("Main")
    Dim wsDst As Worksheet: Set wsDst = wb.Worksheets("Static Data")
    
    'Set the range you want to copy values from
    Dim rCopy As Range:     Set rCopy = wsSrc.UsedRange
    
    'Bring only the values to the destination sheet
    wsDst.Range("A1").Resize(rCopy.Rows.Count, rCopy.Columns.Count).Value = rCopy.Value
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets("Static Data").Range(Sheets("MAIN").UsedRange.Address).Value = Sheets("MAIN").UsedRange.Value` might be a little easier, but good answer.